# How to update flutter main page UI after a change on any module?

Tags: flutter

I am changing the profile of the user on another screen,
I am recalling the main page API and updating the main page UI accordingly.
by using update(id) for GetxBuilder. But it doesn't work.
The change should be reflected on the main page screen which is already in the flutter Getx Stack.
[getx builder reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kw2i.png)

Comment: Please may you provide a [mcve]? It's not easy (or possible) debugging code from an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.